# phpで配列をcsvに変換する関数、またはライブラリはありますか?

Tags: php, csv

タイトルの通りなんですが、配列をうまい感じにCSVに変換する方法を教えてください。

関数を通すだけで必要な場合にであればダブルクオーテーションで閉じてくれたりするのが理想です。
また、fputcsvのようなファイルを出力するタイプではなく、文字列として返してくれるものがよいです。

```
[
[1,"hoge","fuga","piyo\npiyo"],
[2,"hoge","fuga","piyo\npiyo"],
[3,"hoge","fuga","piyo\npiyo"]
];


↓

1,hoge,fuga,"piyo\npiyo"
2,hoge,fuga,"piyo\npiyo"
3,hoge,fuga,"piyo\npiyo"
```

Answer (score 2):

未検証ですが`fputcsv`をメモリに出力すればできるようです。
あとはファイルと同様にアクセスできます。

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');

foreach($csv_data as $line){
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

rewind($fp);

while( !feof($fp) ) {
    print(fgets($fp, 1024));
}

fclose($fp);
```

参考：[fputcsvの結果をファイルに書き込まず変数に格納する](http://blog.katanyan.com/763/)

Answer (score 2):

PHPにはstr_getcsvはあるのに、str_putcsvはありません。なんでもありのPHPにしては珍しいです。なのでメモリに書き込んでから、読み出すしかないと思います。ただSplFileObjectという便利なクラスがありますので、それを使ってみるのはどうでしょう。

```
$csv = new SplFileObject('php://memory', 'wr+');

$csv->fputcsv([1,"hoge","fuga","piyo\npiyo"]);
$csv->fputcsv([2,"hoge","fuga","piyo\npiyo"]);
$csv->fputcsv([3,"hoge","fuga","piyo\npiyo"]);

foreach($csv as $text) {
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: `php://memory` を開く代わりに `SplTempFileObject` でもよさそうですね

Comment: こんなクラスがあったとは知りませんでした。これは使えそうなクラスですね。